# Two 16F873 I2C Communication Addressing

Tags: pic, i2c

I'm trying to communicate between 2 16F873 by using I2C. I wired ;

- SDA > SDA ( Pull-up with 3.3k resistors )
- SCL > SCL ( Pull-up with 3.3k resistors )
- GND > GND ( Common)
- Used 4Mhz crystal on both with x2 22pF cap to OSC1 and OSC1 pins.
- 5V with 10k resistor to MCLR* pin.

Here are the Master and Slave codes which sends "0xFF" data to set all B Pins High. I connected a led with 220ohm resistor to any of these b pins but cant see that the led lights.

So assume i have a problem with addressing of the slave. As i read from the datasheet, address of slave is 7-bit and the last bit (bit 0) indicates data goes from master to slave ( for lsb 0 ). That's why master say 0x20 and slave address is 0x10. (0 is added as LSB).

Do i have to add additional register bits to set anything else? What is the problem here.

I've compiled all codes with PIC C Compiler (5.007)
**Master Code**

```
#include <main.h>

void main()
{

i2c_start();
i2c_write(0x20);//slave address
i2c_write(0xFF);//data
i2c_stop();

 while(TRUE)
   {
      //TODO: User Code
   }

}
```

**Main.h (for master)**

```
#include <16F873.h>
#device ADC=16

#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               //No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O

#use delay(crystal=4MHz)
#use i2c(Master,Slow,sda=PIN_C4,scl=PIN_C3)
```

**Slave Code**

```
#include <main.h>

#use i2c(Slave,Slow,sda=PIN_C4,scl=PIN_C3,address=0x1d)
#INT_SSP                      //Interrupt for I2C activity

 int8 data;
  void sspinterupt()
  { 

  int8 state;

      state = i2c_isr_state();

      if(state < 0x80)           //Master is sending data
     {
        data = i2c_read();      //An array will be needed to store data if more than one byte is transferred
     }
      if(state == 0x80)          //Master is requesting data
     {
        i2c_write(data);
     } 

  }

void main()
{
  set_tris_b(0x00);
  enable_interrupts(INT_SSP);
  enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);

   while(TRUE)
   {  

   output_b(data); //Output data to port B to visualize

   }
}
```

**Main.h (Slave)**

```
#include <16F873.h>
#device ADC=16

#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               //No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O

#use delay(crystal=4MHz)
```

**Proteus Design**

[Proteus Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZgCE.png)

Comment: If, as your source code suggests, your slave has address 0x1D (i.e. `address=0x1d`), and you're using 7-bit addressing, then the master should shift that address left by one and add 0 for write or 1 for reads. So to write to the slave, the master should be sending 0x3A as the address (i.e. 0x1D << 1); Also, in the slave, you need to change `int8 data` to `volatile int8 data` to make sure it's not optimized away.